# Sql to update data

Tags: c#, sql, web-services

**I have following code to set the text box values on page load.**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            localhost.UserRegistration m = new localhost.UserRegistration();
            int user = m.ID(Session["Username"].ToString());
            DataSet ds = m.GetUserInfo(user);
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["emailAddress"].ToString();
                TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["password"].ToString();
            }


        }
```

So when first user opens the page, the user will be shown their email address and password in textbox. when they make changes and click update, the same value that was on page load will be sent to the database, not the new one that is changed.

**I have the following web service method to update the user details**

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Updates a single user")]
        public string UpdateUser(int user, string emailAddress, string password)
        {
            // Create connection object
            int ix = 0;
            string rTurn = "";
            OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            try
            {
                oleConn.Open();
                string sql = "UPDATE [User] SET [emailAddress]=@emailAddress, [password]=@password" + " WHERE [ID]=@user";
                OleDbCommand oleComm = new OleDbCommand(sql, oleConn);

                oleComm.Parameters.Add("@user", OleDbType.Integer).Value = user;
                oleComm.Parameters.Add("@emailAddress", OleDbType.Char).Value = emailAddress;
                oleComm.Parameters.Add("@password", OleDbType.Char).Value = password;


                ix = oleComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (ix > 0)
                    rTurn = "User Updated";
                else
                    rTurn = "Update Failed";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                rTurn = ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                oleConn.Close();
            }
            return rTurn;
        }
```

**This is how table look in database**

[image]

**Client Side Code**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            string email = TextBox1.Text;
            string pass = TextBox2.Text;
            localhost.UserRegistration m = new localhost.UserRegistration();
            int usr = m.ID(Session["Username"].ToString());
            m.UpdateUser(usr, email, pass);

        }
```

Can Somebody tell me why....

Comment: "User Updated" is wrote on console?

Comment: when i run web service in browser, it throws update failed. Checked in database no changes..

Comment: Did you get the return value 'Update failed' or you just don't find the updated values in your database?

Comment: The only possible reasons I can think of are: the columns datatype is not correct or the user you try to update doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you ever tried **specifying a length** for your `char` parameter types?? Not sure what the `OleDbParameter` defaults to, if you don't specify a length for the char....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing up SqlParameters and OleDbParameters. OleDbParameters **does not support named parameters**!!

see **MSDN** [OleDbCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx)

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example:
>
> SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
>
> Therefore, the **order** in which **OleDbParameter** objects are **added** to the
>   OleDbParameterCollection must **directly correspond** to the **position** of
>   the **question mark placeholder** for the parameter in the command text.

I think you should adapt your code to

```
...
oleConn.Open();
string sql = "UPDATE [User] SET [emailAddress]=?, [password]=? WHERE [ID]=?";
OleDbCommand oleComm = new OleDbCommand(sql, oleConn);

oleComm.Parameters.Add("@emailAddress", OleDbType.Char).Value = emailAddress;
oleComm.Parameters.Add("@password", OleDbType.Char).Value = password;
oleComm.Parameters.Add("@user", OleDbType.Integer).Value = user;
...
```

**EDIT**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
      localhost.UserRegistration m = new localhost.UserRegistration();
      int user = m.ID(Session["Username"].ToString());
      DataSet ds = m.GetUserInfo(user);
      if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
      {
          TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["emailAddress"].ToString();
          TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["password"].ToString();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: edited my answer. pls have a look and respond if it did work out.

Comment: Ok that works from the web method but when i call the web method from client side, it doesn't update database. Please check my added code for client above..

Comment: Did you check the values when calling `m.UpdateUser(usr, email, pass);`?

Comment: Saw your code. Add an if condition to check for `!Page.IsPostback`

Comment: Where on Button_Onclick or Page_onload

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it working. Changed sql query like below.

```
string sql = "UPDATE [User] SET [emailAddress]=@emailAddress, [password]=@password" + " WHERE [ID]= "+ user;
```

But it updates the wrong field. emailAddress is updated as user ID, password is updated as email Address.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below line :

```
string sql = "UPDATE [User] SET [emailAddress]=@emailAddress, [password]=@password" + " WHERE [ID]=@user";

To 

string sql = "UPDATE [User] SET [emailAddress]=@emailAddress, [password]=@password where [ID]=@user";
```

and also check the datatype of Id in database is int or not